# How to define: \overmapsto by analogy to amsmath's \overrightleftarrow?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath, arrows

The aim is to define `\overmapsto` which takes in an argument and produces a result similar to `amsmath`'s command `\overleftrightarrow` and friends. But, of course, the arrow type should be `\mapsto`.

> for convenience: amsmath [documentation](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) and [code implementation](https://www.texlive.info/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.pdf))

---

I tried my best to define it on my own; but I do not know how to fix a certain spacing problem (to look better, and be automatic). And it doesn't stretch nicely. Here is the MWE; my attempt is called `\overmapsto` and is based on amsmath's code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\newcommand{\ray}[1]{\overset{\mapsto}{#1}} % <- this is just \mapsto with \overset
\newcommand{\sline}[1]{\overleftrightarrow{#1}} %<- just a renaming of amsmath's \overleftrightarrow
\newcommand{\rline}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}} %<- just a renaming of amsmath's \overrightarrow

%%vv my attempt vv%%

\makeatletter
\def\maptstoarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\mapsto}
\newcommand{\overmapsto}{%
\mathpalette{\overarrow@\maptstoarrowfill@}}
\makeatother

%%^^ my attempt ^^%%

\begin{document}
    
    ray: $\ray{r}$
    
    sline: $\sline{r}$
    
    rline: $\rline{r}$ (also ugly)
    
    -----------------
    
    ugly spacing: $\overmapsto{r}$
    
    better but not automatic: $\overmapsto{r\,}$
    
    doesn't stretch nicely: $\overmapsto{rrrrr}$
    
\end{document}
```

---

Here is the output:

[image: output of MWE]

---

As we can see, the `\mapsto` arrow in `\overmapsto` just *gets too close* to the argument, in this case the letter *r*. Also streching does not work: the vertical line is misplaced.

- ***Q:*** How would one improve the output? Perhaps center the argument a bit more (i.e move the `\mapsto` arrow to the right a teeny-veeny bit)? How to make it stretch correctly?

Notice that `amsmath`'s `\overrightarrow` suffers the same spacing problem as "my" `\overmapsto`, so I could not parrot my way into a better spacing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A version that somewhat scales with the math style and tries to consider the inclination of letters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% not strictly necessary

\newcommand*{\smallerstyle}[1]{%
   \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
   \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
   \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\overmapsto}{\mathpalette\over@mapsto}

\newcommand{\over@mapsto}[2]{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2\mathchar"717F$}%
   \dimen@=\wd0
   \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2\kern0pt\mathchar"717F$}%
   \advance\dimen@-\wd0
   \vbox{%
      \m@th
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr
              \kern2\dimen@$\smallerstyle#1\mapstochar-\mkern-6mu\cleaders\hbox{$\smallerstyle#1\mkern-2mu-\mkern-2mu$}\hfill\mkern-7mu{\rightarrow}$\cr
              \hfil$#1#2$\hfil\cr
             }%
   }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
$\overmapsto{r} \; \overmapsto{rrrrr} \; \overmapsto{A} \; \overmapsto{ABCD} \; \overmapsto{\Gamma}$

$\scriptstyle \overmapsto{r} \; \overmapsto{rrrrr} \; \overmapsto{A} \; \overmapsto{ABCD} \; \overmapsto{\Gamma}$

$\scriptscriptstyle \overmapsto{r} \; \overmapsto{rrrrr} \; \overmapsto{A} \; \overmapsto{ABCD} \; \overmapsto{\Gamma}$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Contrary to the `amsmath` arrows I use a smaller style. If you want to have the same (IMO not wonderful) look of the `amsmath` extensible arrows just remove the two occurrences of `\smallerstyle` in `\over@mapsto`.

Comment: Great campa :-)....

Comment: First impressions: wonderful job! Thank you, (+1). It will take some digesting on my part... After all, I will have to duplicate this for ``\mapsfrom`` and I should also modify ``\overrightarrow`` (because your solution will look better than amsmath's option). But I guess, for now, that's on me for being a newbie. :)

Comment: @campa I am now officially accepting hints on how to do the same thing but with ``\mapsfrom`` (package ``stmaryrd``). The syntax in your helpful answer is a too overwhelming to get anywhere reasonable on my own. Of course, your help on these further topics is *voluntary* (as it was not part of the OP).

Comment: @LinearChristmas I can't check it now but it should be as simple as replacing `\mapstochar` by `\leftarrow`, and `\rightarrow` by `\mapsfromchar`.

Comment: @campa I had tried that but the output looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2KH.png). It was one of the few things that popped into my head to try on my own ;). I also tried to mess with the ``\wd`` and ``\kern`` and ``mu`` stuff and parameters; but did not really understand what they do.

Comment: @LinearChristmas I still can't test right now but I believe you have replaced mapstochar by mapsfromchar, and rightarrow by leftarrow. That would explain the output. But the kerns might need some adjustement too. I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @campa Thank you for commenting. You are right, I had misread your earlier comment; what you suggest there, in fact, I had not tried. Unfortunately, that also didn't work: see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSHr1.png). Take as much time as you need, there is no hurry.

Answer (score 4):

This is only an humble a little suggestion to use just for a only `r`, the `accents` package as this *mwe*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
$\accentset{\mapsto}{r}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a single *r*, it does *not* look bad. But it sort of has a different feel (thickness, etc) than amsmath's similar ``\overrightarrow`` and ``\overleftrightarrow``. So for consistency, I'd have to also use ``$\accentset{\leftrightarrow}{r}$``. Unfortunately, that arrow (for me at least) looks [too far to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7QlA.png). Maybe there's an easier way to fix this? Thank you all the same, and (+1)!

Comment: I have seen and read your comment. I have understood your comment but I think that it is necessary to create another specific macro. I have voted before +1 and now yest :-)..ahahah don't worry for the positive vote. I hope to have given to you an idea. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the package [overarrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overarrows) to deal with these issues.

The `\overmapsto` macro can be defined with:

```latex
\NewOverArrowCommand{overmapsto}{%
  start={\mapstochar},
  trim start=-2.2,
  shift left=0,
  shift right=-6,
  min length=12,
}
```

See the result of:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{overarrows}

\NewOverArrowCommand{overmapsto}{%
  start={\mapstochar},
  trim start=-2.2,
  shift left=0,
  shift right=-6,
  min length=12,
}

\begin{document}

$\overmapsto{r} \quad \overmapsto{rrrrr} \quad \overmapsto{A} \quad \overmapsto{ABCD} \quad \overmapsto{\Gamma}$

$\scriptstyle \overmapsto{r} \quad \overmapsto{rrrrr} \quad \overmapsto{A} \quad \overmapsto{ABCD} \quad \overmapsto{\Gamma}$

$\scriptscriptstyle \overmapsto{r} \quad \overmapsto{rrrrr} \quad \overmapsto{A} \quad \overmapsto{ABCD} \quad \overmapsto{\Gamma}$

\bigskip

\TestOverArrow{overmapsto}

\end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

`\NewOverArrowCommand` and `\TestOverArrow` are two macros from the [overarrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overarrows)  package.